# How can I correctly update my String array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static String[][] possibleOutcomes(Scanner fileScan,int weaponNumber)
   {
      int numberOfOutcomes = (int)Math.pow(weaponNumber,2);
      String[][] outcomes = new String[numberOfOutcomes][numberOfOutcomes];
      String line = fileScan.nextLine();
      Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
      fileScan.nextLine();
      fileScan.nextLine();
      while (fileScan.hasNextLine())
      {
         String userWeapon = lineScan.next();
         String computerWeapon = lineScan.next();
         String possibleTie = lineScan.next();
         if (possibleTie.equals("ties"))
            outcomes[userWeapon][computerWeapon] = possibleTie;
         else
            outcomes[userWeapon][computerWeapon] = lineScan.next();
      }
      return outcomes;
   }
```

Error Message: I think its saying that my inputs are ints even though they are set as String. What should I do?

> RPSL.java:57: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to
>   int
>                   outcomes[userWeapon][computerWeapon] = possibleTie;
>
> RPSL.java:57: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to
>   int
>            outcomes[userWeapon][computerWeapon] = possibleTie;

Comment: `String userWeapon = lineScan.next();` arrays are not accessible by String.  Do you need to convert to a int ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `userWeapon` and `computerWeapon` as Strings, which you can't access an array with. Read an integer from the scanner instead (see [`Scanner#nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--)).

```java
int userWeapon = lineScan.nextInt();
int computerWeapon = lineScan.nextInt();
String possibleTie = lineScan.next();
if (possibleTie.equals("ties"))
    outcomes[userWeapon][computerWeapon] = possibleTie;
else
    outcomes[userWeapon][computerWeapon] = lineScan.next();
```